# need another set of eyes on rails - validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form that takes some fields and adds them to the database. Underneath the form is a html table which displays all the products currently in the DB.

Controller: `pages` , action: `product`

```
#@product is for form capture
#@prods is for displaying list of all products
def product
 @product = Product.new(params[:page])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
   @prods = Product.find(:all)
   flash[:product] = "Product #{params[:pname]} saved successfully"
  else
format.html { render :controller => "pages", :action => "product" }
format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
 @prods = Product.find(:all)
  flash[:product] = "Currently there are #{@prods.size} products"
end
```

View:

```
    <!--show form-->
    <% form_for(@product) do |p| %>   
  <%= p.error_messages %>
  <tr><td><%=p.label 'Product*'%></td>
  <td><%=p.text_field :prod_name%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><%=p.label 'Product Price*'%></td>
  <td><%=p.text_field :prod_orig_price%></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><%=p.label 'Product Discount'%></td>
  <td><%=p.text_field :prod_dis_per%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><%=p.label 'Product Promo Code'%></td>
  <td><%=p.text_field :prod_promo%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center"><td colspan="4"><%= submit_tag "Add Product" %></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<%end%>

  <!--show table-->
  <%if @prods != nil%>
 <tr>
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th>Product Price</th>
  <th>Product Discount</th>
  <th>Product Promocode</th>
 </tr> 
 <% for p in @prods%>
 <tr>
  <td><%=p.prod_name%></td>
  <td><%=p.prod_orig_price%></td>
  <td><%=p.prod_dis_price%></td>
  <td><%=p.prod_promo%></td>
 </tr>
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

The first time around the page is loaded fine. I see the form and I see the table with populated products.  However, when I try to leave all fields empty so I can see validation is working then I see a message 
`uninitialized constant ProductsController`
I have 
`map.resources :products` inside my routes.rb
My rails version is 2.3.5.

I've been at this for a while. I am sure I'm missing something basic because of my lack of understating of rails framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, however to fix your immediate problem you should do this:

1. script/generate controller products
2. create an `index` action in the products controller
3. move your code above in `def product` to your new `def index` action.
4. move your view from `/pages/products.html.erb` to `/products/index.html.erb`.

I'm going to edit this to explain why, but for now this should get you started.

**The why!**

When you define a restful resource in your `routes.rb`, for example by writing `map.resources :products`, rails expects you to write your controllers in a restful fashion.  What this means to you is that if you want a products resource, you're going to need need a `ProductsController` with the following actions (you only have to implement the ones you need): `index, show, new, create, edit, update, delete`.  This should explain why your code wasn't working.

I'm not sure what the contents of your `routes.rb` is, but I'm guessing you have your default route still defined, which would explain why you could browse to `/pages/products`.

When you use `form_for(@product)` rails will generate `<form action="/products" method="post">`, which will map to your `new` action.

Having said all this I suggest you do the following:

1. Read up on [Rails resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html).
2. Refactor your application to be more restful, for example have a dedicate `/new` page for products which displays a form, you can always `<%= render :partial => 'form' %>` in your other actions to share the new product functionality.  This will help with testing and make your code easier to maintain.
3. Take a look at the [Inherited resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) plugin.  It will guide you in the right direction and hopefully save you from writing a lot of code.
4. Take a look at the [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) plugin.  It will help you create semantically correct forms, cut down on your boiler plate code and make your life easier.
5. Read up on [rails partials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).  This will help you tighten up your views.

Rails can have a pretty steep learning curve but there's a lot of literature out there to help you.  I hope this answer points you in the right direction and gives you something to think about.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to imitate the scaffolding because I wanted my validations to work.  This is just a simple app so right now I dont care about being restful. So if I remove `map.resources :products` from my routes.rb and change `form_for (@product)` to `form_for :product` then I no longer get uninitialized constant error. 
One more question regarding form_for. when I view source of my form. parameter names are `products[:prod_name]` in my controller should I  again get them like `Product.new(:prod_name => params[:products][:prod_name]` or will they be somehow automatically mapped. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've not included all the relevant code, your `product` method is missing a `respond_to` block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :controller => "pages", :action => "product" } 
  format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity 
end
```

- [Formats and respond_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#formats-and-respond-to)